# Why ggplot2 cannot plot pois distribution pretty well?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to plot pois distribution with ggplot2, however, I found it cannot return results like base plot. How can I do to make them the same?

Thanks.

```
> plot( dpois( x=100:2000, lambda=150 ), type="b")
```

[image]

```
> plot( dpois( x=100:2000, lambda=150 ), type="l")
```

[image]

```
> ggplot(data.frame(x=c(100:2000)), aes(x)) +
+     stat_function(geom="line", n=11, fun=dpois, args=list(150))
```

[image]

```
> ggplot(data.frame(x=c(100:2000)), aes(x)) +
+     stat_function(geom="line", n=1000, fun=dpois, args=list(150))
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
警告信息：
1: In (function (x, lambda, log = FALSE)  ... : non-integer x = 101.901902
2: In (function (x, lambda, log = FALSE)  ... : non-integer x = 103.803804
3: In (function (x, lambda, log = FALSE)  ... : non-integer x = 105.705706
4: In (function (x, lambda, log = FALSE)  ... : non-integer x = 107.607608
```

[image]

Comment: Try `n = length(100:2000)`. And it wouldn't hurt to have a *named* list `args = list(lambda = 150)`. More readable is better.

Comment: Great, this works, I will add to my answer, thanks :).

Comment: Note that in the accepted answer in your link, `x=c(0:10)`. That's why the number of points to interpolate was chosen to be `n=11`, the length of `x`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks. I did not know utils I saw your previous comment :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After I read [Plotting the poisson distribution using ggplot2's stat_function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644550/plotting-the-poisson-distribution-using-ggplot2s-stat-function), I finally realize the problem comes from the interpolate method of ggplot2.

To avoid this problem, I can calculate the value firstly and then plot with `geom_point` or `geom_line`.

Here goes my answer:

```
> dt = data.frame(x = 100:2000, y = dpois(100:2000, lambda = 150))
> ggplot(data = dt, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

```
> ggplot(data = dt, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the idea from @Rui Barradas :), I can also use `stat_function` to get the same result by changing `n` to a vector:

```
> ggplot(data.frame(x=c(100:2000)), aes(x)) +
+          stat_function(geom="line", n = length(100:2000), fun=dpois, args=list(150))
> ggplot(data.frame(x=c(100:2000)), aes(x)) +
+          stat_function(geom="point", n = length(100:2000), fun=dpois, args=list(150))
```